# Subprocess.check_output timeout not working when using strace

Tags: python, subprocess, python-3.5, strace

I am using python 3.5 and  `subprocess.check_output`  with a `timeout` option to get the output of a subprocess. This works if I call the executable directly, e.g.

```
>>> import subproces
>>> subprocess.check_output(["/usr/bin/gedit"],timeout=1)
...
subprocess.TimeoutExpired: Command '/usr/bin/gedit' timed out after 1 seconds
```

However, if I call

```
>>> subprocess.check_output(["strace","/usr/bin/gedit"],timeout=1)
```

, the `TimeoutExpired` is raised only after I terminate the gedit process myself. So the function `subprocess.check_output` keeps blocking for longer than 1 second.

How would I use the `subprocess.check_output` function (or similar) to get it to raise the exception correctly?